# Any built in way to format WPF bindings?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, iformatprovider

**Scenario**

I can't seem to find a way to format bindings in WPF using an [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx). Currently I've a property on my data source:

```
public int PersonNumber { get; set; }
```

This property is bound to a Label in XAML:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=PersonNumber}" />
```

As you can see it's a number, but should be formatted like 0000.00.000. Currently we use a separate IFormatProvider for such things in our old WinForms application.

**Questions**

- Is formatting like this possible in WPF?

  - If yes, our preferred way is to still use an IFormatProvider, also possible?
  - If no, what is a good alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [ContentStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx) property, which is on all ContentControl descendants including Label.

```
<Label Content="{Binding PersonNumber}" ContentStringFormat="000" />
```

I'm not sure whether WPF's formatting can make use of an IFormatProvider, though.

Answer (score 3):

And to be complete, you could just add a String property to your ViewModel to get full control in C#:

```
public int PersonNumber { get; set; }
public string PersonNumberText { get { return ... } }
```

Comment: In my case it's a DomainModel object wrapped in an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel. Understand your point to create an extra property in the ViewModel, but not sure I'm willing to do that in the DomainModel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  the property `StringFormat` of `Binding`

Nice example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/29/trying-out-binding-stringformat.aspx

Comment: Note that `Binding.StringFormat` doesn't work with `Label.Content`. It only works with string properties, like `TextBlock.Text`.

Comment: @Monty: Sorry, I don't know that for sure.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the posted answers, there's always available the converter way.

Comment: That's true. Seemed as a big detour for such a simple operation.

Comment: Oh, well maybe. The converter is the most general way: it solves almost any situation. However there are some simplifications where a converter is just a "big detour".